# Map bitwise enum to sql column value

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf, t-sql

I have a bitwise enum with FlagsAttribute set over it like this -

```
[FlagsAttribute]
public enum MyEnum
{
    None = 0,
    First = 1,
    Second = 2,
    Third = 4,
    Five = 8,
    Six = 16,
    Seven = 32,
    Eight = 64,
    Nine = 128
}
```

Now, in C# i am storing this value in a property say MyProperty and on save i write this property in my SQL database in integer column. Suppose if i select `First,Second,Five` from code then in database it will be saved as `'11'`.

I know i can fetch value from DB and just need to typecast int value to MyEnum and it will give me the values. But, i want some manipulation to be done on SQL data in some Stored procedure where obviously i can't typecast it to Enum value. So, is there a way out which can let me know about the individual values.

Like in example if 11 is stored, any way that i can get it as `"1+2+8"`

Comment: Can you have varchar column and then save "1,2,8" instead?

Comment: No, i can't change the DB. It's already in production stage.

Comment: SQL is supposed to be bad at bitwise operations; assuming that rather do it in the C# land.

Comment: @jonathan: what?  SQL is fine at bitwise operations.

Comment: @Joe - my (SQL Server Team) sources say "not as good as you think it might be," but it might be one of those marginal/borderline/micro-optimization things.

Comment: "Sources" being MSDN blog posts from 1 or 2 years back.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This may help to get you started:

```
Select 11 & 1 As 'First'
  , 11 & 2 As 'Second'
  , 11 & 4 As 'Third'
  , 11 & 8 As 'Five'
  , 11 & 16 As 'Six'
  , 11 & 32 As 'Seven'
  , 11 & 64 As 'Eight'
  , 11 & 128 As 'Nine';
```

Where `11` is your stored value.

This will return non-zero values for each value that is set (i.e. `Select 11 & 1 As 'First'` returns `1`, `Select 11 & 2 As 'Second'` returns 2, `Select 11 & 4 As 'Third'` returns `0` and so on.

Comment: i personally like this approach for its explicit implementation

Comment: Yeah, this will get me going. Thanks for such a quick response.

Answer (score 6):

You can do [bitwise operations in SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176122.aspx)

```
Select  *
From    MyTable
Where   MyEnum = (1 | 2 | 8)
```

Return which flags are set

```
Select  Case when (MyEnum & 1) = 1 Then 1 else 0 End as First,
        Case when (MyEnum & 2) = 2 Then 1 else 0 End as Second,
        Case when (MyEnum & 4) = 4 Then 1 else 0 End as Third,
        Case when (MyEnum & 8) = 8 Then 1 else 0 End as Fourth,
        Case when (MyEnum & 16) = 16 Then 1 else 0 End as Fifth
From    MyTable
```

Comment: Actually, my question was that i am not aware of the combination. I have only value say 11 in it then i want to get combination from it i.e. 1+2+8. If i had value 133 i need to get value '128+4+1'.

Comment: That will be really helpful, if you can give me a small example.

Comment: Is that what you mean? i.e. which flags are set?

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @MyEnum as Int
set @MyEnum = 11
select
  case when ( @MyEnum & 1 ) = 1 then '1+' else '' end +
  case when ( @MyEnum & 2 ) = 2 then '2+' else '' end +
  case when ( @MyEnum & 4 ) = 4 then '4+' else '' end +
  case when ( @MyEnum & 8 ) = 8 then '8+' else '' end
  as Bitses
```

The (possible) trailing plus is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

```
ID  Name
1   Zero
2   One
4   Two
8   Three
16  Four
32  Five
```

Value of 26 (or 11010) corresponds to One+Three+Four
To get a description for that you can use next request

```
DECLARE @Names VARCHAR(8000) 
SELECT @Names = COALESCE(@Names + ' | ', '') + Name 
  FROM [Play].[dbo].[Enums]
  where (26 & ID)=ID
Select @Names;
```

It will give you next result `One | Three | Four`

if you want to get just ids

```
DECLARE @Names VARCHAR(8000) 
SELECT @Names = COALESCE(@Names + ', ', '') + STR(ID)
  FROM [Play].[dbo].[Enums]
  where (26 & ID)=ID
Select @Names;
```